# Setting a breakpoint in a T4 template

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, t4, clarius-visual-t4

**I'm trying to debug the execution of a T4 template in Visual Studio 2008.**

All the information I'm finding on debugging T4 templates in Visual Studio 2008 say that you can set a breakpoint (red dot) in the template as if it were a regular code file.  I have the Clarius T4 code highlighter installed, so my T4 template is colored, but **I can't set a breakpoint.**  When I click in the margin nothing happens.

I've tried Debugger.Break(), and it launches a new instance of VS.NET, but it can't load the code from my template.  I get a dialog that says "There is no source code available for the current location."  This happens if I have the same project loaded in the another instance of if I spin up a new instance.

What gives?

Comment: Wow, Skynet is now up to T4 model?

Comment: I have the same behavior with VS2008; I am not able to set a breakpoint in the .tt file.  (I also have the Clarius highlighter installed, but I wouldn't think that is related to the breakpoint issue). However, I can set breakpoints in VS2010 in the .tt file.  Not useful to you, but maybe of interest to someone.

Comment: Adding these is necessary in VS2017 and VS2019 as well.  You'd think VS would at least complain they're missing instead of just do nothing and report no error at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK- figured it out.  Launching a new instance is not an option, regardless of what [Oleg's article](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-debugging-code-generation-files/) says.  (No diss to Mr. Sych, his blog is gospel for T4 code generation!)

1. Start a second instance of Visual Studio,
2. Open a file (any file) so the Debug menu shows up.
3. Select "Attach to Process..." and select the other VS.NET instance
4. Save your template in the attached instance of VS.NET (or right-click and select Run Custom Tool)

Voila.

Comment: You can also attach to process from the "Tools" menu.

Comment: This seems to work partially for me. I'm still seeing the "No source code available" in the debugging instance of VS. How do i get the source code?

Answer (score 30):

Set the following:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
```

Then in your template

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

VS will kick off the JIT debugger in a new instance of VS 2010

Comment: Worked perfect... launches second VS for debugging; steps through template and into any debug code you assembly-loaded.  Nice!

Comment: Just one more step for some... Make sure to install the Just-In-Time debugger first by modifying your VS installation! (add it as an individual component)

Answer (score 18):

In Visual Studio ***2013***:

1. Set a breakpoint in the .tt file
2. Right-click the .tt file in the solution explorer
3. Select "Debug T4 Template"
4. Done!

No attaching a second instance of Visual Studio needed.

Comment: Do you know if this is still valid in VS 2019? I don't seem to see a right-click option to debug.

Comment: I don't see that context menu option either.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you turn on the debug option in the template directive:

<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" #>

This makes T4 save the source code and symbol files necessary for debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: The man himself!  Thanks- apparently the red-dot breakpoint just doesn't work in VS2008 but attaching works great.